# Import of 8GB mysql dump takes a long time

Tags: import, mysql

I've got an 8GB MYSQL database dump of InnoDB tables created with mysqldump. I import the data with:

```
mysql -uroot -p my_db < dump.sql
```

An 5 GB dump of the DB was imported within an hour. The 8 GB dump takes 50 hour and counting. When I inspected the processlist with

> SHOW PROCESSLIST;

Most of the time there was a single INSERT query visible with state "'freeing items"

Is there a way, besides copying the raw files, to speed up the import process?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The trick really, is to ensure that the biggest single table fits in the innodb buffer pool. If it does not, then inserts (and import of course) will be extremely slow.

It doesn't matter the size of the whole database, but the biggest single table.

For significantly larger databases, you might want to consider alternative methods of transfering the database, such as filesystem snapshots. This of course works best if your machines are running the same version of the database, OS and architecture.

Comment: [Some very useful reading on that subject](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27341/94577)

Answer (score 6):

How much memory does the machine have? My first guess would be the machine has 6gb or 8gb of memory, and mysql was able to keep the first dump completely in-memory but is somehow swapping hard-core on the second import. Can you run a `vmstat 5` for a few iterations while doing the import and see how heavily the system is swapping?

Comment: It has 8GB. I'll re-run the import and report the vmstat numbers once the available mem becomes scare.

Comment: The only other thing that comes to mind is to disable indexes on the dump, then add them after the data is in the table. From the mysqldump documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html
 --disable-keys, -K
For each table, surround the INSERT statements with /*!40000 ALTER TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS */; and /*!40000 ALTER TABLE tbl_name ENABLE KEYS */; statements. This makes loading the dump file faster because the indexes are created after all rows are inserted. This option is effective only for nonunique indexes of MyISAM tables.

Comment: @opsguy DISABLE KEYS is a MyISAM-ism.

Comment: @MarkR I'm aware, the fact it was InnoDB was added after my disabled keys comment :-)

Comment: @opsguy I did a re-run, but didn't notice any swapping going on with vmstat. Mysqld did not seem to consume a lot of mem.