# Php myadmin import data take too long

Tags: mysql

I have a csv db file. **5 columns, 3,321,986 rows, filesize-199M**

I try to import into mysql database `(php myadmin)`

It's been 4 hours already and it's still importing.

Why does it take so long to import, is this normal?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093921/import-of-8gb-mysql-dump-takes-a-long-time?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's normal with PHPMyAdmin.
Phpmyadmin must translate csv into SQL language and insert this with php functions. It's so long, memory expansive and it depends on the server.

Be careful, if max_execution_time in your php configuration is too short, the import may be interrupted.

Comment: so what is best way to import csv data into table?

Comment: Cut your csv in parts of csv or convert this on mysql dump of insert() and add this with mysql command line client

Answer (score 0):

The import speed depends on the server itself and its connectivity speed.

You can try to chunk the import to several files for example 10 files about 19M each and see if there is a problem with your CSV format at all.

Comment: how to chunk csv file? the file contain million rows, I can't even open completely in excel

Comment: You can use this http://www.scaled-solutions.com/blog/open-source-csv-file-splitter